# how to read a property from a Json?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I read `query.students.queryType`?

```
query = {
  "students": [
    {
      "searchField": "lastname",
      "queryType": "exact",
      "query": {
        "text": "jack"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do mean exactly? `query.students[i].queryType` where `i` is the array index you want…

Comment: @WillAlexander query.students[i] returning TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined - query.students returning undefined. i tried query["students"] same undefined

Comment: Think about what exactly you are trying to achieve. `students` is an array.

Comment: trying to read the queryType from students collection

Comment: Different for every student? Read how? Create a new array?

Comment: I have only one students collection

Comment: I realize that. 1) Is the queryType different for every student? 2) What do you want to do with the queryTypes? Do you want to create a new array from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is because of, `query` type is `string` (stringified json), and you are trying to get `students` property of a string type. So it is `undefined`.
First convert the stringified json to a json object using:

```
const jsonObj = JSON.parse(query);
```

Then get the value of `students` members using `forEach`:

```
jsonObj.students.forEach(student => {
   console.log(student.queryType) 
   // you can get the value of queryType for each student 
});
```

Comment: core.mjs:7621 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') it didnt work either also i tried with map and filter

Comment: Can you give more information about, where the value of `query` comes from? Does it come form an async function like `fetch` or shomething similar?

Comment: **query** is string const which comes from non-async method

Comment: if it is a string, do you parse that to json using `JSON.parse(query)` and then do the operation on it?

Comment: i can try but the **query** input is after performing ** JSON.stringify **

Comment: Not `JSON.stringify` I siad `JSON.parse`! Cause the only reason that comes to my mind is that `query` type is a string so naturally `query.students` is undefined.

Comment: it did helped, i appreciate if you post answer so i can tick it as answer

Comment: I edited the answer and added ‍`JSON.parse` part. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Access it like this:

```
query.students[0].queryType
```